# List all Email in folder using Outlook MAPI

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'd like to list all of my emails in a specific folder by using Outlook MAPI. I have tried the following code,

but it only shows 400 out of the 20,000 emails in the folder. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could please show me how to list *all* of the emails.

```
Sub EmailListinFolder()

Dim mn As Long
Dim Message As String
Dim item As Object
Dim NS As Object
Dim Folder As Object

'Get the MAPI Name Space
Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Allow the user to select a folder in Outlook
Set Folder = NS.PickFolder
For Each item In Folder.Items
  If item.Class = olMail Then

      Message = item.Subject & "|" & item.CreationTime
      If Len(Message) Then
        mn = mn + 1
      End If
  End If
Next item

MsgBox (mn)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that an online profile? Most likely you end up opening too many items (for each loop keeps all items referenced until the loop exits). Use `Table` object instead - see example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/folder-gettable-method-outlook.

Comment: I meant "online" as in non-cached vs cached (OST) Exchange profile.

Comment: It's online email service(IMAP), I have tried Table object, but Table object also can access only 400 limited count. Thank your help. How can I access next email more than limited count 400?

Comment: IMAP4 is very different from an Exchange mailbox. Are you sure yo actually see all 20,000 messages in that folder?

Comment: I can see only 400 emails in email client. I can see all emails in web email pages. Can I see all emails in VBA?

Comment: If yo go to File | Accounts, is your account set to sync only a subset of messages?

Comment: I can't find sync option of subset message. Thanks Dmitry. I think 400 limitation is the imap service's limit. The other imap service(gmail) is not 400 limit in VBA and outlook client. I'll ask the imap site of the limitation.